# Leaving website disclaimer through PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Due to legal reasons, I want every external hyper link posted on my forum to first link to a `You're leaving this website and are being redirected to a website that is not our property...` -disclaimer page. Something like http://www.mydomain.com/?leave=FINALURLHERE would do fine, but how do I set up this system?

I can easily make a script that does it for all URLs, but I only want this to happen to external URLs. Can anybody push me towards the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure this disclaimer applies in your case? Hint: it **most probably** doesn’t. 99% of these disclaimers don’t do anything and have no legal validity.

Comment: Just check whether your host (`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`) matches the URL or not?

Comment: So your question is actually "how can I tell an internal and an external URL apart"?

Comment: These would be the same legal reasons that make every other website in the world need do the same thing, right?

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph, in my case, it definitely does ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're using some form of BBCode on your forums. You can just edit that to add your leaving page first.

If you're not, then you'll have to resort to some rather messy JavaScript. Something like:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), l = links.length, i,
    domain = location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname+"/";
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( links[i].href.substr(0,domain.length) != domain) {
        links[i].href = "/exit.php?target="+encodeURIComponent(links[i].href);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a very basic forum system that only has a wysiwyg editor. A simple solution would be adding it before every generated URL, but I just have no idea on how to make it only work for external URLs.

A function checkURL($stringhere) to edit the URLs and return the complete string would be the nicest, but I'm not experienced enough with the PHP language to make these kind of things myself ;-)